# How to check if a table is in use by some procedure or view on AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am using AWS Redshift. I have more than 100 tables in one schema, out of which the data of some tables get refreshed on a daily basis while some tables do not get refreshed at all.
I have figured out the tables whose data do not get refreshed.
Before having them dropped, I want to check if they are currently in use by any function/procedure/view of the same schema or any other schema.
Is there any way to check this out on Redshift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this code online, don't remember where so I am sorry I can't credit...

I recommend saving this as a view so you can always run this easily.

And if you have views that use certain tables that you want to drop, you can use `WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING` at the end of the view. That way the table will be able to be dropped even if there is a view using it.

The code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    srcobj.oid AS src_oid
    ,srcnsp.nspname AS src_schemaname
    ,srcobj.relname AS src_objectname
    ,tgtobj.oid AS dependent_viewoid
    ,tgtnsp.nspname AS dependent_schemaname
    ,tgtobj.relname AS dependent_objectname
FROM
    pg_catalog.pg_class AS srcobj
INNER JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_depend AS srcdep
        ON srcobj.oid = srcdep.refobjid
INNER JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_depend AS tgtdep
        ON srcdep.objid = tgtdep.objid
JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_class AS tgtobj
        ON tgtdep.refobjid = tgtobj.oid
        AND srcobj.oid <> tgtobj.oid
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace AS srcnsp
        ON srcobj.relnamespace = srcnsp.oid
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    pg_catalog.pg_namespace tgtnsp
        ON tgtobj.relnamespace = tgtnsp.oid
WHERE tgtdep.deptype = 'i' --dependency_internal
AND tgtobj.relkind = 'v' --i=index, v=view, s=sequence
and src_schemaname <> 'pg_catalog' and src_schemaname <> 'information_schema';
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ItayKirgner. This is truly the magical query that I needed. 
I wanted to ask that we have condition tgtobj.relkind = 'v' to filter out the dependant objects which are views only. How can I include procedures and functions as well in the dependant objects list? Also, what is the meaning of index and sequence? And we have used condition tgtdep.deptype = 'i' for internal dependancy only, will it miss out of any other dependant objects?
Thank you many many times again!!

Comment: @SidhantGupta: I'm also in need of this. Did you figure out how to list stored procedures? Thank you.